# Why is it that I can't use react and express library from global space(installed via npm i -g pkgName) but I can use react-scripts from global space

Tags: reactjs, express, npm

Is there something I do not know, I guess there's something that prevents this import though I we can access other global installed modules from anywhere like jest, live-server, react-scripts, http-server, etc. Any help in this area is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the answer for this is to use the command

```
npm link react
```

This command will simply make a symlink to the global package, thus when the bundler is run it will be able to look inside the packages it created symlinks for inside the current node_modules folder of the package.

Answer (score 1):

Since no code was shown, I assume you are trying to `import React from 'react';` having React installed only globally.

Frequently, you can use globally installed packages (like `Jest`) via terminal seamlessly, but if you are trying to import something from a globally installed package in your code, it is getting kind of problematic since the thing that resolve those imports in the code is the bundler which is normally unaware of presence of any global packages.

Depending on bundler you use, you probably could configure the bundler in some way, so, it will know how to use global packages.

However, commonly, people just install packages on project level instead.

Comment: But I don't find any way to load from global path using node bundler. Can you show how to do it with node, I'm a beginner to node environment.
Or you may tell how build a package for offline installation.